# Spring actuator endpoints does not work on the application port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, port, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to enable the actuator endpoints on the same port as the application port (specified in the application.properties file by the server.port=8080) but for some reason, it does not work. When I run the application, I can get back the response from the application but not from the actuator endpoints. I can see the logs mention the endpoints being exposed beneath base path '/actuator' as shown in the screenshot below. But when I try to hit the actuator URL, it gives a 404.

URL, **not working**:

- http://localhost:**8080**/actuator
- http://localhost:**8080**/actuator/health
- http://localhost:**8080**/actuator/info

However, if I specify a separate port in application.properties for the actuator endpoints with the property (management.server.port=9000) then it works fine.

URL, that's **working**:

- http://localhost:**9000**/actuator
- http://localhost:**9000**/actuator/health
- http://localhost:**9000**/actuator/info

The only difference is about the port number but from what I read in the spring documentation, the actuator endpoints should by default be enabled on the application port if we don't specify the management.server.port.
Can someone please explain what am I missing here?[image]
PS: The application run logs are exactly the same with or without specifying the management.server.port, hence, this one screenshot is without specifying the management port. 
Also, I tried giving the same port number for both the property (server.port and management.server.port) but the same problem occurs. The application works on that port but the actuator endpoints do not.
I am using the spring-boot version 2.0.6

These are the contents of my application.properties file:

```
camel.springboot.main-run-controller=true
camel.springboot.name=AppName
camel.rest.data-format-property.prettyPrint=false
camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path=/*

server.port=8080
management.server.port=9000

management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
management.endpoint.beans.enabled=true

logging.level.org.springframework = INFO
logging.level.org.apache.camel.spring.boot = INFO
logging.level.org.apache.camel.impl = DEBUG
```

Here are the dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Could you please add your full application.properties file or even a github link?

Comment: and spring boot version

Comment: And your dependencies from pom.xml/gradle.build file

Comment: @dgebert added the application.properties file

Comment: @Lebecca I updated the spring-boot version. For your reference, it is 2.0.6

Comment: @theshadog Please check, I have added the dependencies

Comment: i think the (`8080`) "side effect" might be caused by `camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path=/*` , have you tried the (simple) workaround, setting : `management.server.port=8080` (resp. `${server.port}`)?

Comment: ..if that fails, please refer to [current camel-spring-boot-sample](https://github.com/apache/camel-spring-boot/tree/master/examples/camel-example-spring-boot) (without `camel.component.servlet.mapping.context-path=/*`)

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the Spring Boot Actuator [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-monitoring)

> Exposing management endpoints by using the default HTTP port is a
>   sensible choice for cloud-based deployments. If, however, your
>   application runs inside your own data center, you may prefer to expose
>   endpoints by using a different HTTP port.

it serves the Actuator using the default HTTP port (which is 8080). I did a quick check and could confirm this with Spring Boot 2.1.X and 2.2.X.

Try to remove the `management.port` from your config and if this does not work then the problem might come from an additional (custom) configuration in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @rieckpil 
I confirmed it too with another dummy spring application, however, removing the management.port does not make it work at all.

Comment: Also, there is no other additional custom configuration in the application that could possibly affect the health endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Please set the below in application.properties file

```
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true 

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but this didn't change anything, still having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `management.server.port=9000`, this property overrides `server.port=8080`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, what was causing this for me was a conflict between the context I declared for camel and the one being used for spring actuator.

So, at application.yml I had these 3 contexts:

```
server: servlet: context-path: myservercontext/v1
camel: component: servlet: mapping: contextPath: /*
management: endpoints: web: base-path: "/"
```

I think after the request hits the server it gets lost on this ambiguity so i solved it by changing these contexts to:

```
server: servlet: context-path: myservercontext/v1
camel: component: servlet: mapping: contextPath: /camel/*
management: endpoints: web: base-path: "/"
```

This worked out nicely for me since all my resources where grouped under "/camel" anyway but as I tested I found out this also works:

```
server: servlet: context-path: myservercontext
camel: component: servlet: mapping: contextPath: /v1/*
management: endpoints: web: base-path: "/"
```

Just note that in this last scenario the health route won't be under "v1".

I would never have figured out the cause of this problem if it wasn't for this question, even if it wasn't solved yet, so I thank you a lot for posting this and hope my solution will manage to help others ^^

Answer (score 0):

#### Sample server and management configuration

Below is a sample configuration.

You can have a separate server port and one for management where the actuator will run.
For example, you may have `port 8001` as your `SERVER` port and maybe have `port 8000` as your `MANAGEMENT` port.

I will use the `applications.properties` file formatting for my answer. Please update accordingly if using `application.yml`

```
# SERVER CONFIGURATION
server.port=8001
# Server - Compression :
server.compression.min-response-size=2KB
server.compression.enabled=true
server.compression.mime-types=text/html,text/css,text/csv,text/javascript,text/markdown,text/plain
# Server - Error handling :
server.error.include-binding-errors=on_param
server.error.include-exception=true
server.error.include-message=on_param
server.error.include-stacktrace=on_param
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=true
server.error.path=/error
# Server - Session :
server.servlet.encoding.charset=utf-8
server.servlet.session.tracking-modes=cookie
server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age=30
server.servlet.session.cookie.secure=true
server.servlet.session.cookie.name=cookie_session_duesclerk
#
#
# MANAGEMENT CONFIGURATION
management.server.port=8000
springdoc.use-management-port=true
management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true
management.server.base-path=/management
management.server.ssl.enabled=false
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include= health, openapi, swaggerui
#
```

Please note the custom management path `/management`

```
management.server.base-path=/management
```

You can remove/retain this based on what you need